# Contiki os and rapsberry PI 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, contiki

I want to make my raspberry pi3 a border router in 6LOWPAN network .

I asked  some friends how to do that , they advice me to set up contiki os in my raspberry pi .

Then How to set up contiki os in raspberry pi 3 to operate like a border router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to set up a raspberry pi as a border router in a 6LOWPAN network. But I can tell you how to install the contiki toolchain on your raspberry. It is a start, at least.

Open a terminal and run the follwing commands:

Get Your Raspi Up To Date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Get Contiki:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd /path/to/your/new/contiki/folder
git clone https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki.git
cd contiki
git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
git pull
```

Set up all dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev  libssl-dev openssl
sudo apt-get install gcc-msp430
sudo apt-get install gcc flex bison libboost-graph-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential binutils-msp430 gcc-msp430 msp430-libc msp430mcu
sudo apt-get install mspdebug binutils-avr gcc-avr gdb-avr avr-libc avrdude openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre ant libncurses5-dev bridge-utils build-essential binutils-msp430 gcc-msp430 msp430-libc msp430mcu
```

Optional: Get tinyos_tools (like "motelist", to see connected devices)

```
sudo apt-get install tinyos-tools
```

I would like to recommend you the open book Internet of Things in 5 days. I learned a lot from this book, it even has a chapter called "4.5. UDP on IPv6 and the Border Router". You can get it for free from github in .pdf or .epub format: https://github.com/marcozennaro/IPv6-WSN-book/tree/master/Releases
I hope I could help you a bit.

Regards